# How to write entity and post request for a table with a foreign key (by id)

Tags: java, mysql, maven, http

I have a table "product" with two FKs manufactor and category. I want to write a query so, that when you add a product, you don't create a manufacture every time, but select it by id from the available ones.
[image: uml diagram for tables] 
Now I have:
  My Product entity:

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="manufactor",  referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Manufactor manufactor;

    public void setManufactor(Manufactor manufactor) {
        this.manufactor = manufactor;  }

    public Manufactor getManufactor() {
        return manufactor;  }
```

My Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Product addNewProduct (@RequestBody Product product ) {
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }
```

*My request should look something like this:*

```
{   "name": "Alakazai",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 58,
    "manufactor": 2,
    "category": 3
}
```

But when I use postman I have the error:

```
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Invalid JSON input: Cannot construct instance of `com.store.Entity.Manufactor` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.store.Entity.Manufactor` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 5, column: 16] (through reference chain: com.store.Entity.Product[\"manufactor\"])",
```

What mistake did I make? In product entity or somewhere else? I will glad to any explanation

If you need, my project on github: [Project](https://github.com/Asel06/online_store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to persist in the controller layer.

A better practice would be to have a class ProductForm that match the json body.
Next you can make checks on it (positive price by example), then convert it to a Product instance using entities to map your Manufactor, and then persist it.

By example :

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Product addNewProduct (@RequestBody ProductForm product ) {
    return productservice.register(product);
}
```

ProductForm:

```
public class ProductForm{

    private String name;
    private int price;
    private int quantity;
    private int manufactor;
    private int category;

    //Add getters & setters here
    //...

}
```

Service :

```
public Product register(ProductForm form) {
    checkForm(form); //business checks goes here, should raise exception if failure
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setPrice(form.getPrice());
    product.setName(form.getName());
    product.setQuantity(form.getQuantity());
    product.setCategory(categoryRepository.findById(form.getCategory()));
    product.setManufactor(manufactorRepository.findById(form.getManufactor()));
    return productRepository.save(product);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by json body? Can you tell me more about what should be in this class

Comment: This class should be a simple DTO with fields that are only prmitives. The values of the field are the value of the variables of the sent json, not mapped to any entity.
this allow you to store in memory the body of the request.
I added exemple in my previous response

Comment: I get errors: ```Error:(21, 56) java: incompatible types: java.util.Optional<com.store.entity.Category> cannot be converted to com.store.entity.Category
Error:(22, 60) java: incompatible types: java.util.Optional<com.store.entity.Manufactor> cannot be converted to com.store.entity.Manufactor
Error:(25, 40) java: incompatible types: com.store.entity.Product cannot be converted to com.store.entity.ProductForm```

Comment: This is more or less pseudo code, i can't know the implementations of your repositories. You must adapt the code i provided to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have in the Manufactor a @OneToMany to Product class? Like this:

```
@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "manufactor",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>()
```

What I would do is this:

- add a @OneToMany in Manufactor
- create a DTO layer (you shouldn't use the persisted object to make REST requests). In that layer, create a DTO object like Product but add a manufactor id. Or just create a copy of the Product class and in the post, add a pathvariable in which you put the manufactor id.
- in the controller, take the manufactor id from the dto or from the pathvariable, do a find on the db, put the manufactor object on the product that is to be stored and do the save.

Comment: 1) I have @OneToMany in Manufactor; 2) you mean this?: ```@Column(name = "manufactor", nullable = false)
    private int manufactor;``` How I can add a pathvariable? 3) I need to ```manufactorRepository.getById(id)``` in the post request for product?